# How to use IAsyncEnumerable within a message in protobuf-net.grpc?

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net

So, recently I learned about how to do streaming with protobuf-net.grpc with the help of `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. This all works fine and dandy, but I'm facing a bit of an issue right now.

For some of my calls, I'd like to call with both some metadata as well as the stream as parameter.

For example:

```
[OperationContract]
Task<bool> UploadPicture(ProfilePictureQuery query);
```

With the following signature:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ProfilePictureQuery
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]> RawDataStream { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string FileExtension { get; set; }
}
```

However, when trying to call this, I'm getting an exception like `'Status(StatusCode=Unimplemented, Detail="Method is unimplemented.")`. I know that status responses are a bit cryptic, so I figured out that this is actually just an issue with the parameter.

How do I do this then?

I also tried to do it with the following signature:

```
[OperationContract]
Task<bool> UploadPicture(IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]> rawDataStream, string fileExtension);
```

With the same outcome, as I'm apparently only allowed to provide a single parameter (True to the grpc definition of one message parameter and one response output).

Sooo, how do I do this then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two separate concepts here:

- gRPC allows a stream of messages via `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` (instead of a `Task<T>` for a single message)
- however, each individual message must be complete and self contained; the marshaller (per-message serializer) is synchronous only

So: you can use `IAsyncEnunerable<T>` as the parameter or return of a service method, but not as a field on a message.

If you need to provide a stream and additional metadata a few options exist:

- use http headers (via `CallContext` as a second parameter)
- have two service calls - one that initiates things and gets the metadata, one that returns the stream
- have a stream with some optional fields in the message, and only populate the optional fields in the first or last message

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - Any chance you have some documentation on the CallContext available?

Comment: Besides that, I just tried it and it works like a charm, thanks a lot

Comment: @Sossenbinder mentioned here some: https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted